# Smt2-lib: why do I get a difference in behavior between `declare-const + assert` and `define-fun`?

Tags: z3, smt, model-checking

I have a z3 model written in the smt2-lib format. I noticed that when I use:

```
(declare-const flat1 (Seq Dummy))
(assert (= flat1 (unroll dummyFormula1)))
```

The model is sat, while when I use:

```
(define-fun flat1 () (Seq Dummy) (unroll dummyFormula1))
```

the model is reported as unknown.
Why is the difference important? If it helps, I can produce a minimal version of my model.

**Edit #1** - A minimal example

Be sure to run it using z3 from github master because of [this bug](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/2120). You can swap between the two versions I indicated with `A)` and `B)` below.

```
(set-option :produce-models true)

; --------------- Basic Definitions -------------------

(declare-datatype Dummy (A B))

(declare-datatype Formula
  ((Base (forB Dummy))
   (And  (andB1 Formula) (andB2 Formula))
   (Or   (orB1 Formula) (orB2 Formula))
   (Not  (notB Formula))))

(declare-const dummyFormula1 Formula)
(assert (= dummyFormula1 (Base A)))

(declare-const dummyFormula2 Formula)
(assert (= dummyFormula2 (And (Base A) (Base A))))

; --------------- Some functions -----------------------

(define-fun
  in_list ((o Dummy) (l (Seq Dummy))) Bool
  (seq.contains l (seq.unit o)))

(define-fun
  permutation ((l1 (Seq Dummy)) (l2 (Seq Dummy))) Bool
  (forall ((o Dummy)) (= (in_list o l1) (in_list o l2))))

(define-fun-rec unroll ((f Formula)) (Seq Dummy)
  (match f
    (((Base j)    (seq.unit j))
     ((And f1 f2) (seq.++ (unroll f1) (unroll f2)))
     ((Or  f1 f2) (seq.++ (unroll f1) (unroll f2)))
     ((Not f1)    (unroll f1)))))

; -------------- The question -------------------------

;; Here are two versions that should express the same idea, but try commenting
;; the first one and uncommenting the second one!

;; A)

(declare-const flat1 (Seq Dummy))
(assert (= flat1 (unroll dummyFormula1)))

;; B)

; (define-fun flat1 () (Seq Dummy) (unroll dummyFormula1))
; -----------------------------------------------------

(declare-const flat2 (Seq Dummy))
(assert (= flat2 (unroll dummyFormula2)))

(assert (permutation flat1 flat2))

; --------------- Verify -------------------
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Comment: A minimal version would indeed help.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin added a minimal example, please tell me if you can reproduce the behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say without looking at the internals of z3. But I want to point out that while the two constructs are very similar, there's a subtle difference.

If you look at page 62 of the standard (http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf), it says:

```
(define-fun f ((x1 σ1) · · · (xn σn)) σ t)

  with n ≥ 0 and t not containing f is semantically equivalent to the command sequence

(declare-fun f (σ1 · · · σn) σ)
(assert (forall ((x1 σ1) · · · (xn σn)) (= ( f x1 · · · xn) t)).
```

So, when you use the `define-fun` form, you are explicitly putting in a quantified formula. When you use the `declare-const`/`assert` as you did manually, this quantification does not exist.

Now you can argue that there *are* no parameters in your case, so there should be no difference, and I'd agree with you. But you're also using quite new features like `match`, `define-fun-rec` etc., so obviously z3 is tripping over something here. Since you have a minimal example already, why not post it to the z3 github issues site and get some feedback there. I suspect perhaps the macro-finder is missing a case and can't instantiate this particular case, but really hard to say and there might also be a good reason for it.

If you do post there and get a good answer, please update this question so we know what's going on!

Comment: Great advice, thanks @Levent Erkok. I'll update this thread if I get an explanation!